# How to block certain URL from robots.txt file?

Tags: robots.txt

This is simple question but also I have a confusion.

Below is the code which I wrote in my *robots.txt*:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /phpmyadmin/  
Disallow: /login/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /articlesubmission/  
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I want all bots to follow my site but they should not follow these URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/.....
http://www.example.com/login/.....
http://www.example.com/newsletter/..... 
http://www.example.com/articlesubmission/.....
```

My doubt:  **Is my above *robots.txt* code is correct?**
I followed this code from [StackOverflow robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt).

Comment: Yes, your _robots.txt_ is correct.

Comment: @Danny Looks good :-)

Comment: @Danny Based on the amazingly quick crawling and indexing StackOverflow receives, I don't think their webmaster is wrong ;-)

Comment: @dan  Thanks dan. I was little bit confused with this that's why though to ask you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have defined your entries correctly.

Just to be clear, adding the name of a directory with a trailing slash will block that directory and **everything** within it; including if there is a live page on the directory address.

However your `Allow: /` is superfluous and will have no effect as you are already allowing the entire site apart from the directories you have disallowed, so this entry should be removed.

You can find more info on how robots.txt works with Google here: [Robots.txt Specifications](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Now i understood. I am very confusing person.